# How to print screen of a SWT window from a SWT based application

Tags: java, printing, swt

I would like to allow a user to print an application window she or he interacts with. I am looking for examples how to implement such a print screen functionality for SWT based GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple method is (which we use in our product) to take the screenshot of the window and then print it using SWT printer api.

See the below code for taking screen capture of a window.

**`>> Orignal Window`**

[image]

**`>>Screen capture`**

[image]

**`>>Code`**

The code tells only about the screen capturing of a particular window. Check the printer api usage here [SWT Printer Usage](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#printing). In this code I am creating a GC for the display and then copying the area in which the shell is present.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyleRange;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;

public class ScreenCaptureTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] names  = {"Harry", "Sally", "Jhon", "Tim", "Scott"};
        String[] msg    = {"Hello World!", "Today is a nice day to walk", "I am bored", "This is how you take widget capture", "Ha Ha Ha!! That's funny !"}; 

        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Screen Capture");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

        final Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));


        /*
         * Create Table Widget
         */

        Table table = new Table(composite, SWT.BORDER|SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.H_SCROLL|SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);

        table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        TableColumn columnName = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
        columnName.setText("Name");
        columnName.setWidth(100);

        TableColumn columnMsg = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
        columnMsg.setText("Message");
        columnMsg.setWidth(200);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        {
            TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE, 0);
            item.setText(0, names[i]);
            item.setText(1, msg[i]);            
        }

        /*
         * Create StyledText Widget
         */

        StyledText text = new StyledText (composite, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setText("0123456789 ABCDEFGHIJKLM NOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        StyleRange style1 = new StyleRange();
        style1.start = 0;
        style1.length = 10;
        style1.fontStyle = SWT.BOLD;
        text.setStyleRange(style1);

        StyleRange style2 = new StyleRange();
        style2.start = 11;
        style2.length = 13;
        style2.foreground = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
        text.setStyleRange(style2);

        StyleRange style3 = new StyleRange();
        style3.start = 25;
        style3.length = 13;
        style3.background = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
        text.setStyleRange(style3);

        /*
         * Create Button
         */

        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Capture");
        button.pack();

        button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
        {
            public void handleEvent(Event event) 
            {
                /*
                 * Widget capturing logic
                 */
                GC gc = new GC(display);
                final Image image = new Image(display, shell.getBounds());
                gc.copyArea(image, shell.getBounds().x, shell.getBounds().y);
                gc.dispose();

                Shell popup = new Shell(shell);
                popup.setText("Captured Image");
                popup.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() {
                    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                        image.dispose();
                    }
                });

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(popup, SWT.NONE);
                canvas.setBounds(0,0,image.getImageData().width, image.getImageData().height);
                canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                        e.gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                    }
                });
                popup.pack();
                popup.open();
            }
        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }

        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SWT's `StyledText` widget directly supports printing its contents.

Otherwise, you'll have to build your own print function using the `org.eclipse.swt.printing` classes `Printer`, `PrinterData`, and `PrintDialog`.

The standard pattern for printing involves the following steps:

- Create a `Printer` object
- Start a print job
- Create a `GC`
- Start a page
- Draw on the page
- End the page
- Repeat the start, draw, and end cycle for as many pages as you need to print
- End the print job
- Clean up